# Rails turbo stream destroy action handling inexistent parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

The following execution upon hitting a button `<%= button_to fa_icon('bomb', class: 'fa-lg'), importattribute, class: 'button alert small', method: :delete %>`  in Rails 7

```
Started DELETE "/importattributes/1" for ...
Processing by ImportattributesController#destroy as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Importattribute Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "importattributes".* FROM "importattributes" WHERE "importattributes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/importattributes_controller.rb:53:in `set_importattribute'
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/importattributes_controller.rb:47:in `destroy'
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

is hitting the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column importattributes.importattribute_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...importattributes".* FROM "importattributes" WHERE "importatt...
```

upon

```
  def destroy
    authorize @importattribute
    @supplierimport = Supplierimport.find(@importattribute.supplierimport_id)
    @importattribute.destroy
    redirect_to supplierimport_path(@supplierimport), notice: "Import attribute was successfully destroyed."
  end
```

with the standard private Rails method

```
    def set_importattribute
      @importattribute = Importattribute.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Why is Rails looking up in PG `importattribute_id`  instead of `id` ?
This is also occuring in the test suite & I am quite puzzled by it.

Comment: question amended

Comment: Can you show destroy action?

Comment: method added to question

Comment: Try to search your codebase for `importattribute_id`. Double check your Importattribute model. Maybe there are callbacks firing?

Comment: I don't see this SQL query `@supplierimport = Supplierimport.find(@importattribute.supplierimport_id)` in your log. Probably that's the problem

Comment: @mechanicov Oh it is there, I just did not include it to avoid polluting the stack when first writing the question.  Besides the error is explicit: `column importattributes.importattribute_id` when the query should be on `importattributes.id`

Comment: @MaxPaprikas I ran that check and no callbacks (other thatn the scaffold generated ones) are firing.

Comment: @Jerome Could you share the source code on github? At least minimal code to reproduce the issue. Also I can help you via discord if you want

Comment: unfortunately, I am not at liberty of doing that for the moment. In the meantime, for reasons unclear, the problem has vanished - the application and tests run as expected.